# What are rules for using single and double quote in php?

Tags: php, quotes

I would like to know when to use a single quote within a double quote and vice-versa.  The scenario becomes more complicated when there is a variable involved.

For example, I was trying to insert values into the database using the following code:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO demo_table (name, dob, age, address) VALUES ("$name", "$dob", "$age", "$address")';
```

It did work but it interpreted $name, $dob, $age and $address as strings and not a variable holding values, so actual values were not saved.

Are there any rules when to use single quote, double quote, quotes with backslash(like \' or \") and what to do when there is need to use quotes within quotes. I have also seen some codes using concatenation sign(.) within quotes. What is the logic behind that?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)?

Comment: If you used PDO with prepared statements you wouldn't have such a question

Answer (score 2):

database characters requires single quotes ' '.
So keep the characters in query in ' '.

```
$query="INSERT INTO table_name (name, email, password) VALUES ('$username','$email','$password')";
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be like this:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO demo_table (name, dob, age, address) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$dob."', '".$age."', '".$address."')";
```

Comment: Why "should" it be like this and why are you using concatenation when you could use the variables in your double quoted strings directly?

Answer (score -1):

In php a string in single quotes is a constant value and a string in double quotes is a dynamic string.
so you can use:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo_table (name, dob, age, address) VALUES ('$name', '$dob', '$age', '$address')";
```

OR

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo_table (name, dob, age, address) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$dob."', '".$age."', '".$address."')";
```

Notice the . either side of the `$name`, `$dob`, `$age`, `$address` variable which concatenates string values.

And it may be better to create your queries as strings. Doing that allows you to echo the queries when checking to ascertain that produces values you are expecting.
Hope that helps.